# Creating order programmatically not working in magento

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to create order programmatically I have a below code for order creation

```
 require_once 'app/Mage.php';
 Mage::app();
 $getid =$this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
 $quotedetails = Mage::getModel('quotemanager/quotedetails')->load($getid);
        $quoteFname = $quotedetails->getFirstname();
        $quoteLname = $quotedetails->getLastname();
        $quoteEmail = $quotedetails->getEmail();
        $quoteNumber = $quotedetails->getMobileNumber();
        $quoteAddress1 = $quotedetails->getAddressLine1();
        $quoteAddress2 = $quotedetails->getAddressLine2();
        $quoteCity = $quotedetails->getCity();
        $quoteState = $quotedetails->getstate();
        $quotecZipcode = $quotedetails->getZipCode();
        $quoteCountry = $quotedetails->getcountry();

        foreach (Mage::app()->getWebsites() as $website) {
            $websiteId = $website->getId();
            foreach ($website->getGroups() as $group) {
                $stores = $group->getStores();
                foreach ($stores as $_store) {
                    $store = $_store;
                }
            } 
        } 

        $_quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->setStoreId($store->getId());
        $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->setWebsiteId($websiteId)->loadByEmail($quoteEmail);
        if (!$customer->getId()) {
            $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer');
            $customer->setWebsiteId($websiteId)
                    ->setStore($store)
                    ->setFirstname($quoteFname)
                    ->setLastname($quoteLname)
                    ->setEmail($quoteEmail)
                    ->setPassword("password");
            $customer->save();
        }

        //Assign Customer To Sales Order Quote
        $_quote->assignCustomer($customer);

        $getproduct_id = Mage::getModel('quotemanager/quoteproductdetails')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('quote_details_id', $getid);
        foreach ($getproduct_id as $product_id) {
            $productid = $product_id->getProductId();
            $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productid);
            $_quote->addProduct($product, new Varien_Object(array('qty' => $product_id->getQuantity())));
        }
        // Set Sales Order Billing Address
        $billingAddress = $_quote->getBillingAddress()->addData(array(
            'customer_address_id' => '',
            'prefix' => '',
            'firstname' => $quoteFname,
            'middlename' => '',
            'lastname' => $quoteLname,
            'suffix' => '',
            'company' => '',
            'street' => array(
                '0' => $quoteAddress1,
                '1' => $quoteAddress2
            ),
            'city' => $quoteCity,
            'country_id' => $quoteCountry,
            'region' => $quoteState,
            'postcode' => $quotecZipcode,
            'telephone' => $quoteNumber,
            'fax' => '',
            'vat_id' => '',
            'save_in_address_book' => 1
        ));

        // Set Sales Order Shipping Address
        $shippingAddress = $_quote->getShippingAddress()->addData(array(
            'customer_address_id' => '',
            'prefix' => '',
            'firstname' => $quoteFname,
            'middlename' => '',
            'lastname' => $quoteLname,
            'suffix' => '',
            'company' => '',
            'street' => array(
                '0' => $quoteAddress1,
                '1' => $quoteAddress2
            ),
            'city' => $quoteCity,
            'country_id' => $quoteCountry,
            'region' => $quoteState,
            'postcode' => $quotecZipcode,
            'telephone' => $quoteNumber,
            'fax' => '',
            'vat_id' => '',
            'save_in_address_book' => 1
        ));
        // Collect Rates and Set Shipping & Payment Method
        $shippingAddress->setCollectShippingRates(true)
        ->collectShippingRates()
        ->setShippingMethod('flatrate_flatrate')
        ->setPaymentMethod('checkmo');

        // Set Sales Order Payment
        $_quote->getPayment()->importData(array('method' => 'checkmo'));

        // Collect Totals & Save Quote
        $_quote->collectTotals()->save();

        try {
            // Create Order From Quote
            $service = Mage::getModel('sales/service_quote', $_quote);
            $service->submitAll();
            $increment_id = $service->getOrder()->getRealOrderId();
            $getidbyquoteid = Mage::getModel('quotemanager/managequotes')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('quote_id', $getid)->getFirstItem(); 
            $id = $getidbyquoteid->id;
            Mage::getModel('quotemanager/managequotes')->load($id)->addData(array('order_id'=>$increment_id))->setId($id)->save();
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addSuccess("order created successfully");
        } catch (Exception $ex) {
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError("Unable to create order");
        }

        // Resource Clean-Up
        $_quote = $customer = $service = null;
```

The above code is not working it returns error like

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getRealOrderId() on null

What is the problem in my code...?

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
  $increment_id = $service->getOrder()->getRealOrderId();
```

use below code

```
  $increment_id = $service->getOrder()->getIncrementId();
```